# How do I fix a MySQL ghost foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I had an InnoDB table called Things. This table had foreign key constraints on Field1, Field2 and MoarFields.

I renamed this table to `things`, and renamed the fields to `field1`, `field2`, and `moar_fields` (all lowercased).

At this point, all my foreign keys to the newly named table `things` are suddenly gone. This is fine, I didn't want them either way, but I didn't actually delete them.

Then I tried modifying a field name in a different table, which also needed to be lowercase, but it complains about a foreign key constraint preventing this.

```
ALTER TABLE `member` CHANGE COLUMN `MemberID` `member_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
/* SQL Error (1025): Error on rename of './database/#sql-411_3e7' to './database/member' (errno: 150) Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed */
```

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` tells me the problem is:

```
121001 12:02:12 Error in foreign key constraint of table database/Things:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_MemberRole_Member" FOREIGN KEY ("MemberID") REFERENCES "member" ("MemberID") ON DELETE CASCADE
InnoDB: Renaming table `database`.`#sql-411_3e7` to `database`.`member` failed!
```

If I do `show create table things`, I do not see any foreign keys. Though I do see 4 normal keys with the name of my foreign keys.

If I take a look at the `schema_information` database however, I can see that InnoDB has 4 keys stored there, for a table that does no longer exists, namely `Things`. Those are probably the problem.

How do I remove those ghost keys? I could recreate the database and copy just the data, but it's quite large, so if possible, I'd rather not do that.

Please let me know if you want/need any information.

Comment: Can you show the statement with which you try to create a foreign key on your new fields?

Comment: Excuse me, I stated the problem partially incorrect. I did add the result of what I tried to do though. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

late answer but try this to find constraints

use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE;

Answer (score 0):

you can use following commands to get rid of it.

```
drop index FK_MemberRole_Member;
Drop constraint FK_MemberRole_Member;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really in a position anymore to test whether this solution works, but hopefully it'll help other people! If anyone comments that it worked, I'll mark it as as the accepted answer :)